# Fill PDF with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

For a management application to taxes, made with Laravel 8, I need to dynamically populate the fields of a pdf file.
The file has the Italian F24 template, and i need to fill the field.
In my application i've installed `barryvdh / laravel-dompdf`, I then converted the pdf to html, load the html and try the conversion to pdf and download it.

I have the problem that when I switch from html to pdf, with method `createPDF()` it totally loses formatting.
If while I try to render the pdf converted to html, before manipulating it, on the browser it can be seen correctly.

Do you have any suggestions or advice?

- my code:

DelegheController

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Deleghe\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use PDF;

class DelegheController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * @return Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('deleghe::index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     * @return Renderable
     */
    public function createPDF()
    {
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Welcome to ItSolutionStuff.com',
            'date' => date('m/d/Y')
        ];

        $pdf = PDF::loadHTML(file_get_contents(storage_path().'/quietanza.html'));

        return $pdf->download('stampa_quietanza.pdf');

    }

    /**
```

Comment: Show your HTML. If you're loading a CSS file inside of your HTML, it might be better to inline the CSS instead.

Comment: It's too long the html and overflow the form character limits

Comment: Currently we only need to make new implementations on the software we have and therefore we are still bound to use this development model